# FFMPEG segment file long time record video black

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I am trying to record 30 seconds MP4 segment file for very long record time using Decklink Duo2 HD.
All works fine for about six hours, but suddenly the MP4 start whit problems.

Whit VLC is impossible read file, and i have this error message:
main warning: buffer too late (-437792 us): dropped

If use FFPLAY i see video but audio in not in sync.

Here is the command:

ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 1150000000 -threads 48 -f dshow -channels 8 -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format uyvy422 -rtbufsize 100M -r 25 -i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 30 "G:\LoopCH1%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.mp4"

Comment: Make sure your ffmpeg is not old.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was about segment command.
I used `-reset_timestamps`.